# Class within class in Java object name not found

Tags: java, oop

```
class Library {

    String libraryName;
    String address;

    Library(String namelibrary)
    {
        libraryName=namelibrary;
    }

    Book[] books=new Book[150];

    void addBook(Book newBook)
    {
        books[i]= newBook;
        i++;
    }

    class Book
    {
        String title;
        boolean borrowed;
    }
}

public class test{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         Library firstLibrary = new Library("10 Main St.");
         Library secondLibrary = new Library("228 Liberty St.");
         firstLibrary.books[0]= new Book("Maths");
    }
}
```

When I run this code I receive the message that it cannot find the symbol Book.

However as per my (week) understanding, this error should not be coming as Book is the class within Library and I am defining it from its object
Please help and guide. Appreciate your help in advance

Comment: This is not real code, hard to help You. MAYBE package declatations, imports ??? Hard to say

Comment: You need to tell the compiler that you want the `Book`  that is inside `Library` so you need `new Library.Book` not just `new Book`. Also, it is more common to declare classes in their own file and to avoid nested classes like that.

Comment: Since `Book` is not a "first level" class, such as `Library`, it is not directly reachable in the context of your `test` class. To actually instantiate a new `Book` item, you should call your `Book` constructor like `Library.new Book("Maths");`.

Comment: Also, if you plan to instantiate multiple "Library" classes, you should probably make `String library` and `String address` private using the keyword `private`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Book class is a member of `Library`. So you can only access it through Library class. So your code should be

```
 firstLibrary.books[0]= firstLibrary.new Book("Maths");
```

Then your next error is you do not have appropriate Constructor of Book which receives name. Have a one and it should be ok then.

```
class Book {

        String title;
        boolean borrowed;

        public Book(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

    }
```

Ok, looks like one more error on the way in this method

```
void addBook(Book newBook) {
        books[i] = newBook;
        i++;
    }
```

You never declared your **i**. Please declare it and initialize.

```
class Library {

String libraryName;
String address;
private int i = 0;
..
..
```

Looks like you started Java recently. So just avoid nested classes for now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out and pointing the error
actually I am new to Java but my code was very bulky and i wanted to put here the part which was causing the problem and remove the other parts.
so in the process i removed the int i declaration and constructor of Book along with the not related part

Anyway, thanks once again. I wasn't expecting a very overwhelming response

Answer (score -2):

try defining the class book just after the class library like

```
class Library {


class Book{

    String title;
    boolean borrowed;

}
String libraryName;
String address;

Library(String namelibrary)
{
    libraryName=namelibrary;
}

Book[] books=new Book[150];

void addBook(Book newBook)
{
    books[i]= newBook;
    i++;
}


}
public class test{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 Library firstLibrary = new Library("10 Main St.");
 Library secondLibrary = new Library("228 Liberty St.");
 firstLibrary.books[0]= new Book("Maths");

}}
```

Comment: It's still an inner class right now... It will produce the same error

Comment: The problem does not come from the `Book` class position inside the enclosing class, it is how a new `Book` item is instantiated.